# Examples of perturbative force-free electrodynamics on top of vacuum solutions?

Tags: black-holes, astrophysics, resource-recommendations, plasma-physics, neutron-stars

Imagine I have a solution $A_{(0)\mu }$ for the four-vector potential of vacuum electrodynamics. That is, the solution fulfills source-free Maxwell equations $F^{\mu\nu}_{(0)\;\;;\nu} = 0$ with $F_{(0)\mu\nu } = A_{(0) \mu,\nu} - A_{(0)\nu,\mu}$.

Now I would like to introduce small currents so that I can find a solution that is close to the original vacuum fields and approximately fulfills force-free electrodynamics, i.e. $F^{\mu\nu}J_\nu = 0$ while $F^{\mu\nu}_{\;\;\;;\nu} = J^\mu$. Naturally one can solve this problem iteratively by finding a field $J_{(0)\mu}$ such that $F^{\mu\nu}_{(0)}J_{(0)\nu} = 0$. The correction to the electrovacuum field is then computed as $F^{\mu\nu}_{(1)\;;\nu} = J^\mu_{(0)}$, $F^{\mu\nu} = F^{\mu\nu}_{(0)} + F^{\mu\nu}_{(1)}$.

I am looking for resources that do such computations in any context (Newtonian, relativistic, flat space-time, curved space-time,...). I am particularly interested in practical algorithms, possible weaknesses of this method, and applications to astrophysics of compact objects.

---

To sketch what I am looking for, I have a set of exact electrovacuum solutions near black holes and neutron stars (i.e. the Kerr metric) with interesting properties that could lead to strong acceleration of particles. However, 1) these fields need to be supported by an accretion disk and this disk will leak plasma into the fields, thus making the equations non-vacuum, 2) the fact that particles are accelerated in the field means that it should not be vacuum anyway. So one definitely needs to add some plasma to the mix for physical consistency of the model.

Comment: I think you need to be more specific about what exactly your problem and final aims are. Depending on that, perhaps, you'd be better able to search for the optimum method of performing perturbation expansions.

Comment: @Avantgarde I added some comments to the effect. I would, however, appreciate examples of such computations even for, say, white dwarf magnetospheres.

Comment: Are you looking for things like https://arxiv.org/abs/1605.02253 or https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.02273, or did I miss something more specific in your question?  Anatoly Spitkovsky (at Princeton) has a bunch of papers on neutron star simulations and I am guessing at some point he started with some force-free approximation (he likes to say "let's learn to walk before we run").  You might start by searching for his work to see if it's relevant to your question.

Comment: @honeste_vivere Thanks, the idea of the methods these papers use is very similar to what I was thinking to use.